# Copy import to variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I have a trouble studing python,

At first I need to create a python script, which will import this and copy text to the variable named text.

Right now, I have:

```
 import this as t
 text = t;
```

It doesn't work for me. Who can help me?

### Update

I need to have the result:

```
print(text);
```

Result

```
"The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters"
```

Comment: Have you tried 'import this as text'?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? What happens, and how is that different to what you expect?

Comment: You mean "_The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters_" text? Hm... why would you need this? Sounds like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: text is in `this.s` but encrypted. Module decrypts it and sends directly on screen so it doesn't keep it in variable. use `print(this.__file__)` to get path to this module and you can open it in editor to see code.

Comment: @MatthewLavin I need to write print(text) and get the result "The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters"

Comment: What is `this`?

Comment: you can't do `print(text)` because `text` doesn't keep this text. Module keeps in variable only encrypted version and it converts it directy to `print()` which sends on screen.

Comment: `this` is a special module which, when you import it, displays a mini-essay entitled "The Zen of Python". There is no attribute in the module that has as its value the contents (at least, the unencrypted contents) of that essay, though.

Comment: First, as others have asked, *why*? And secondly, you seem to be confusing the *result* of an import (the imported module) wth a side-effect (printing the Zen).

Comment: @chepner, turns out, the obfuscated text is in `this.s`.

Comment: @chepner so, ok, how can I get the text from this to variable?

Comment: `this.s.split('\n')[0]` is close to what you want; that still needs to be decoded.

Comment: @Artsom but *why* do you want to do this? What purpose does it serve?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
>>> import this
# wall of text follows
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.decode(this.s, 'rot13')
"The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters\n\nBeautiful is better than ugly.\nExplicit is better than implicit.\nSimple is better than complex.\nComplex is better than complicated.\nFlat is better than nested.\nSparse is better than dense.\nReadability counts.\nSpecial cases aren't special enough to break the rules.\nAlthough practicality beats purity.\nErrors should never pass silently.\nUnless explicitly silenced.\nIn the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.\nThere should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.\nAlthough that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.\nNow is better than never.\nAlthough never is often better than *right* now.\nIf the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.\nIf the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.\nNamespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!"
```

Now you can do `text = codecs.decode(see above)`.

Comment: Ah, I was wondering if there was a ROT-13 decoder in the standard library. You can also build one using `str.maketrans`: `this.s.translate(str.maketrans(this.d))`.

Answer (score 1):

This is code from module `this`

If you use

```
text = "".join([d.get(c, c) for c in s])
```

instead of `print()` then you get your text

```
s = """Gur Mra bs Clguba, ol Gvz Crgref

Ornhgvshy vf orggre guna htyl.
Rkcyvpvg vf orggre guna vzcyvpvg.
Fvzcyr vf orggre guna pbzcyrk.
Pbzcyrk vf orggre guna pbzcyvpngrq.
Syng vf orggre guna arfgrq.
Fcnefr vf orggre guna qrafr.
Ernqnovyvgl pbhagf.
Fcrpvny pnfrf nera'g fcrpvny rabhtu gb oernx gur ehyrf.
Nygubhtu cenpgvpnyvgl orngf chevgl.
Reebef fubhyq arire cnff fvyragyl.
Hayrff rkcyvpvgyl fvyraprq.
Va gur snpr bs nzovthvgl, ershfr gur grzcgngvba gb thrff.
Gurer fubhyq or bar-- naq cersrenoyl bayl bar --boivbhf jnl gb qb vg.
Nygubhtu gung jnl znl abg or boivbhf ng svefg hayrff lbh'er Qhgpu.
Abj vf orggre guna arire.
Nygubhtu arire vf bsgra orggre guna *evtug* abj.
Vs gur vzcyrzragngvba vf uneq gb rkcynva, vg'f n onq vqrn.
Vs gur vzcyrzragngvba vf rnfl gb rkcynva, vg znl or n tbbq vqrn.
Anzrfcnprf ner bar ubaxvat terng vqrn -- yrg'f qb zber bs gubfr!"""

d = {}
for c in (65, 97):
    for i in range(26):
        d[chr(i+c)] = chr((i+13) % 26 + c)

print("".join([d.get(c, c) for c in s]))

# --- added code ---   
text = "".join([d.get(c, c) for c in s])
```

---

You can find path to module using `print(this.__file__)` and then you can open in editor to see code.

Comment: I think this is the better answer because you learn how the module is structured and, to solve the problem, you need to look at the original code and understand it.

Answer (score 0):

**Example:**

```
from this import s
import codecs
my_text_variable = codecs.decode(s, 'rot13')
print(my_text_variable)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
...
...
...
```

Comment: It's doesn't work. At first I got the result `Gur Mra bs Clguba`, The second, I can't assign the result to the variable

Comment: I have tested it and it worked as expected for me with `python3.6.6` (as you can see in my answer). Further more you can assign the result to variable if you want. The `s` variable contains the string so you can do eg.; `my_assigned_var = s` and then `my_assigned_var ` variable will also contain the string.

Comment: I have improved my answer. I think now it is more understandable.